# Como pegar o conteudo das divs dinâmicas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Tenho o seguinte código, que é adicionado dinamicamente:

```
var m = 0;
$$("#add_medicamento").click(function(){
m++;
var medicamento = $$("#select_medicamento").val();
var qnt = $$("#quantidade").val();
$$("#lista_medicamentos").append('<li class="swipeout">'+
                                '  <div class="swipeout-content item-content">'+
                                '    <div class="item-inner">'+
                                '       <div class="item-title-'+m+'">'+medicamento+'</div>'+
                                '       <div class="item-after-'+m+'">'+qnt+'</div>'+
                                '    </div>'+
                                '  </div>'+
                                '  <div class="swipeout-actions-right">'+
                                '    <!-- Add this button and item will be deleted automatically -->'+
                                '    <a href="#" class="swipeout-delete">Apagar</a>'+
                                '  </div>'+
                                '</li>');
 })
```

E estou tentando pegar o nome do medicamento (dentro da div class="item-title" que é dinâmica), e a quantidade de medicamentos inseridos (dentro da div class="item-after" que também é dinâmica).

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas sem sucesso:

```
var medicamentos = $$("#lista_medicamentos .item-inner");

medicamentos.each(function(idx, li){
    var teste = $(li);
    alert(teste);
})
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Algum alerta é emitido?

Comment: Sim!  `[Object Object]`, e se eu mudar para o console.log, aparece o seguinte: `Object [ <div.item-inner> ]`

Comment: Então está funcionando. No lugar do `alert` tente colocar `console.log(teste.find(".item-title-*").html())`

Comment: Opa, deu certinho @AndersonCarlosWoss .Se quiser postar como resposta, confirmo!  Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira que você fez está correta, apenas incompleta. Com o seletor `#lista_medicamentos .item-inner` você apenas captura a `div.item-inner`, então para capturar o nome do medicamento, basta procurar o elemento `.item-title-*` que é filho deste. Veja que como o valor de `m` varia quando o elemento for inserido no DOM, o caractere `*` no seletor servirá de coringa. Basicamente ele procurará o elemento que possui uma classe que começa com `.item-title-`. Veja abaixo:

```
var medicamentos = $$("#lista_medicamentos .item-inner");

medicamentos.each(function(idx, li){
    var title = $(li).find(".item-title-*");
    console.log(title.html());
})
```

---

Adendo: como o nome do medicamento está no elemento que é o primeiro filho de `.item-inner`, seria possível fazer `var title = $(li).first()`, sendo, possivelmente, mais rápido que utilizar o `find`.

Comment: Como coringa, não funcionou, mas coloquei uma variável dinâmica, e deu certo, pois podem ser vários medicamentos!

Comment: Como assim "variável dinâmica"?

Comment: `function cadastrar(){  
    var t = 0;
    var medicamentos = $$("#lista_medicamentos .item-inner");
    medicamentos.each(function(idx, li){        t++;
        var mq = $(li);
        console.log(mq.find(".item-title-"+t+"").html()+ ' - '+ mq.find(".item-after-"+t+"").html());
    })
}`

Comment: Pode tentar o seletor `[class^="item-title-"]` também

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar **classe** e **id** ao mesmo tempo. A **id** fica de forma fixa.

```
var teste = $('#teste55').val();
alert(teste);
```

Na parte de HTML:

```
<div id="teste55" class="item-title-'+m+'">'+medicamento+'</div>'+
```

Assim ele pegará o valor da `div` dinâmica.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @Stéfano